# Iterating over zipped lists in python

Tags: python, zip, loops

I have the following:

```
class Trade:
    def __init__(self):
        entry = [0, 1, 2, 3]
        exit = [1, 2, 3, 4]
        met = [0, 0, 0, 0]
        self.stats = zip(entry, exit, met)



t = Trade()

for entry, exit, met in t.stats:
        met = 1

for entry, exit, met in t.stats:
    print(entry, exit, met)
```

I am expecting all values of `met` to be 1. But that is not the case. What is the reason for this, and how can I make it so that the modifications to `met` are reflected in the instance of `Trade class t`. Does the for statement produce a copy of t.stats rather than iterating through its original copy?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you loop over the values of a list, the values are assigned to local variables. Changing those local variables will not change the original values stored in the list.

Use a `enumerate()` call to add indexes, then use that index to change the original list:

```
for i, (entry, exit, met) in enumerate(t.stats):
    t.stats[i] = (entry, exit, 1)
```

Comment: Oh I see, what is @mgilson 's comment referring to? I cannot modify t.stats?

Comment: @Joshua: you can modify `t.stats`, you cannot modify individual entries in the nested tuples. Replace the tuples wholesale (like I did in my answer).

Comment: I usually do something like `for i, (entry, exit, _) in enumerate(t.stats):`, the `_` is kind of a signal that says "no one cares about me outside of this statement".

Answer (score 2):

The following will do it:

```
t.stats[:] = [(entry, exit, 1) for entry, exit, met in t.stats]
```

The reason your code doesn't work is that `met = 1` simply rebinds `met` to point elsewhere. This has no effect on `t.stats`.